# What's the best way to interrupt a running program in response to another program in a script?

Tags: bash

My usecase is a yad program that uses another script that mounts a filesystem. What i'm currently doing and somewhat unsatisfied by is a complex dance of kill and wait to 'simulate' having the return value of the yad available.

(mount script is above the snippet and irrelevant. Just be aware that it sends a write to the 'FD' - not SEL_FD - when it quits or remounts, which the code below uses to loop or not depending on GAME_SEL and REMOUNTED)

```
#stdout to FD (to get the selection on exit and still be a background proc)
GAME_SEL=$(mktemp -u -p "${XDG_RUNTIME_DIR}" "${0##*/}.XXXXXXXXXX")
mkfifo "$GAME_SEL"
exec {SEL_FD}<> "$GAME_SEL"

yad \
--width=600 \
--height=660 \
--center \
--window-icon "applications-games" \
--title "Dosbox Launcher with games overlay" \
--text=" Click to play"  \
--list \
--noheaders \
--search-column=2 \
--regex-search \
--column="Path:HD" \
--column="Game Config:TEXT" \
--button=gtk-close:1 \
--button=gtk-ok:0 \
"${CONF_LIST[@]}" \
 2>/dev/null 1>& "$SEL_FD" &
yad_pid=$!

#wait for copy-on-write-drive notification (quit or mount doesn't matter)
#and kill the dialog using yad signal for graceful failure termination
( read -u "$FD"; kill -USR2 $yad_pid ) &
pidof_killer=$!

#wait for yad termination and read its stdout on a timeout. If triggers timeout, it's empty
wait $yad_pid 2>/dev/null
read -t 0.1 -u "$SEL_FD" GAME
exec {SEL_FD}>&- #close FD

#kill the killer if still active
kill $pidof_killer 2>/dev/null
wait $pidof_killer 2>/dev/null #supresses 'Terminated' output too
#if the killer was already dead (it caught a notification), this is 0, otherwise != 0
REMOUNTED=$?
```

As far as i can tell i need this complexity because I need to background the yad process in order to be able to kill it in response to the mount script FD notification and this in turn causes the return value of yad (not the stdout which is captured by SEL_FD) to be uncapturable by the main script process. Is there a much better way of doing this logic? It feels like this is far too complex.

Comment: Note, with bash `wait pid` has a return code equal to that of the process waited on.

Comment: That makes sense. I am already using that from the $? at the last line now that i think about it, just using the lack of any output and if the killer was still alive to differentiate if it was quit/unmount or remount of the filesystem instead of using the yad return code directly... that could get rid of the 'wait $pidof_killer' i guess.